# Not able to implementing RMAN Script (Backup)

Tags: oracle, database-backups, rman

I have been trying to take backup of database by using following script.
But it is unable to finish (complete) backup.

It is only initiating the backup but I can't see it at a particular location.

```
==========================================================
SCRIPT
==========================================================

#!/bin/sh

rman_bkp()

{

# RMAN Backup

echo "test "$2 $1"

echo "Backup in progres.."

{

rman << ZZ

connect target /

run 

{

configure default device type to disk;

configure device type disk parallelism 4;

configure device type disk backup type to compressed backupset;

configure controlfile autobackup format for device type disk to '$1/%F.ctl';

allocate channel c1 device type disk format '$1/d_%s_%p_%T' MAXPIECESIZE 10G;

allocate channel c2 device type disk format '$1/d_%s_%p_%T' MAXPIECESIZE 10G;

allocate channel c3 device type disk format '$1/d_%s_%p_%T' MAXPIECESIZE 10G;

allocate channel c4 device type disk format '$1/d_%s_%p_%T' MAXPIECESIZE 10G;

allocate channel c5 device type disk format '$1/d_%s_%p_%T' MAXPIECESIZE 10G;


backup as compressed backupset full database;

backup current controlfile;

BACKUP ARCHIVELOG ALL DELETE INPUT;

}

crosscheck backup;

delete noprompt obselete;

delete noprompt expired backup;

ZZ

} > $2
}

backup()

{

echo

BKPDIR="/u01/apex/APEXDB/BACKUPS/$BKP_TYPE"

LOGFILE="/u01/apex/APEXDB/BACKUPS/logs/RMAN_${BKP_TYPE}_$DATE.log"

echo $BKPDIR

rman_bkp $BKPDIR $LOGFILE

}

echo

echo "Initiating Backup at "`date`

echo

DATE=`date +%d%m%I%M`

echo "Initiating Apex Database backup"

BKP_TYPE="FULL_DB"

backup $BKP_TYPE

echo

echo "Completed Backup at "`date`

echo





============================================================
ERROR
============================================================
sh rman_backup.sh

Initiating Backup at Fri Feb 1 11:36:09 IST 2019

Initiating Apex Database backup

/u01/apex/APEXDB/BACKUPS/FULL_DB
test /u01/apex/APEXDB/BACKUPS/logs/RMAN_FULL_DB_01021136.log /u01/apex/APEXDB/BACKUPS/FULL_DB
Backup in progres..
rman_backup.sh: line 9: rman: command not found

Completed Backup at Fri Feb 1 11:36:09 IST 2019
```

I would be thankful if I get proper explanation of the script along with the errors &  it's solution .

Comment: You should correct your question formatting.

Comment: The error is "rman: command not found" which is fairly clear. Your environment isn't set up properly so that executable can't be found in your $PATH. You need to set that and $ORACLE_HOME properly.

Comment: Hey @Alex Poole  now it is not showing that error but It's not taking backup also I can't find recent backup file at my location and even in rman>list backup summary

Comment: output- 
Initiating Apex Database backup

/u01/apex/APEXDB/BACKUPS/FULL_DB
test /u01/apex/APEXDB/BACKUPS/logs/RMAN_FULL_DB_01020344.log /u01/apex/APEXDB/BACKUPS/FULL_DB
Backup in progres..

Completed Backup at Fri Feb 1 15:44:27 IST 2019